# Generate multiple draws (calls) of a given method in java (simulated lottery)

Tags: java, arrays, simulation, lcg

I received the task of simulating a lottery draw in java. The program skeleton yields the method generateOneDraw, which creates 6 random numbers between 1 and 49

```
static int[] generateOneDraw() {
    int numbers[] = new int[NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT_PER_DRAW];
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; ++i) {
        int nextNumber;
        do {
            nextNumber = generateNextRandomNumber();
        } while(numberIsInArray(nextNumber, numbers));
        numbers[i] = nextNumber;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

We are then required to implement a function that simulates the lottery draw over 5 weeks and stores them in the variable draws. I believe this should be done over a two-dimensional array. Am I right in this way of thinking? Any pointers on implementing it would be greatly appreciated.

```
static void generateAllDraws()
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Nevermind, I did it with a simple two dimensional array and it worked.

Comment: I would develop a simple `Draw` class to hold the digit `List`s and have a `List<Draw>` to store them.

Comment: Drawing random numbers doesn't guarantee uniqueness - this probably isn't what you want at all. You want an array with the numbers already in it, random shuffled.  You current approach has the possibility of never terminating.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but since I'm pretty new to java I think I might need some additional explanation. I'm looking to do this as simply as possible, even if it is not quite as efficient. Could you elaborate?

Comment: have u considered using hashmaps?

Comment: @Boris the Spider; This was the code given to me by my professor. This is not the skeleton code in its entirety, just the relevant method.

Comment: @NinaHain sorry to say, but your professor is an idiot in that case. Anyone who writes `O(∞)` code shouldn't be teaching anything.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Maybe their professor was planning to start with an example which has some pitfalls to be improved?

Comment: Since it's meant for practise, I don't really care. I am well aware that LCG generators are rather tricky, but this is not the essence of my problem.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Your comment points out why big-O analysis is not the be-all and end-all. Well-constructed acceptance/rejection algorithms, while theoretically unbounded, have been known to outperform O(1) algorithms in practice because of their very low expected run-time.  For an example see [Marsaglia's polar method vs Box-Muller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box–Muller_transform) for generating Gaussians.

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems like home work, I will not go into much detail but you can either:

1. Create a 2 dimensional list, as per your initial reasoning;
2. Create a `Draw` class which represents a lotto draw, and create multiple instances of this class. Each `Draw` class could have a `Date` which would denote *when* did the draw take place.

Both approaches should work, the second approach is a little more object oriented.

Comment: Hey @npinti! You're right, it is homework - word for word it states to "Implement the function generateAllDraws, which creates 5 draws and stores them in the static variable draws."

Comment: @NinaHain: Then I would recommend you try both approaches mentioned above, or any other which other people here might propose :)